# Error:Unfortunately app has stopped when retrieving data using JSON

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-emulator

I am new to android application development. I have this source code which I am trying to make it work, I took it from a tutorial online.

The problem I am facing is that when I run this code on a device or on an emulator I get the error of:

> Unfortunately MainScreen has stopped

But my data get entered into the mysql database which I have created in wamp.

Here is my code:
1.AllProductsActivity

```
package com.example.androidhive;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;


    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";


    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";


    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);


        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        new LoadAllProducts().execute();


        ListView lv = getListView();


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();


                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);

                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
    }



  2.EditProductActivity:

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

        EditText txtName;
        EditText txtPrice;
        EditText txtDesc;
        EditText txtCreatedAt;
        Button btnSave;
        Button btnDelete;

        String pid;

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // single product url
        private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

        // url to update product
        private static final String url_update_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/update_product.php";

        // url to delete product
        private static final String url_delete_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/delete_product.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
        private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

            // save button
            btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

            // getting product details from intent
            Intent i = getIntent();

            // getting product id (pid) from intent
            pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

            // Getting complete product details in background thread
            new GetProductDetails().execute();

            // save button click event
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // starting background task to update product
                    new SaveProductDetails().execute();
                }
            });

            // Delete button click event
            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // deleting product in background thread
                    new DeleteProduct().execute();
                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
         * */
        class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Getting product details in background thread
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Check for success tag
                        int success;
                        try {
                            // Building Parameters
                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                            // getting product details by making HTTP request
                            // Note that product details url will use GET request
                            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                            // check your log for json response
                            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                            // json success tag
                            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully received product details
                                JSONArray productObj = json
                                        .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                                // get first product object from JSON Array
                                JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                                // product with this pid found
                                // Edit Text
                                txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                                txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                                txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                                // display product data in EditText
                                txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                                txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                                txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                            }else{
                                // product with pid not found
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }


            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
         * */
        class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Saving product
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                // getting updated data from EditTexts
                String name = txtName.getText().toString();
                String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
                String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

                // sending modified data through http request
                // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                        "POST", params);

                // check json success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully updated
                        Intent i = getIntent();
                        // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                        setResult(100, i);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // failed to update product
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once product updated
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        /*****************************************************************
         * Background Async Task to Delete Product
         * */
        class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Deleting product
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // product successfully deleted
                        // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                        Intent i = getIntent();
                        // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                        setResult(100, i);
                        finish();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

        }
    }


3.JSONParser

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}

4.MainScreenActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity{

    Button btnViewProducts;
    Button btnNewProduct;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

        // Buttons
        btnViewProducts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewProducts);
        btnNewProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // view products click event
        btnViewProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching All products Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        // view products click event
        btnNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching create new product activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}

5.NewProductActivity:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
        try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                        }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is LogCat Error:

```
12-10 15:37:48.934      338-568/com.example.androidhive E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 15: http://10.0.2.2 /android_connect/create_product.php
            at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:776)
            at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
            at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:48)
            at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:95)
            at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:64)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-10 15:37:49.974      338-338/com.example.androidhive E/WindowManager? Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405490f8 that was originally added here
    android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405490f8 that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
            at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
            at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:76)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
            at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:56)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart
```

Comment: There is a error in the link you have provided.It is were the error occurs.I think its because of the space next to 2 before /.

Comment: You can not do any UI activity in doInBackground method.

Comment: I fixed that error, still app is not working properly (Getting same error again) What else can I do to fix thoes errors? @Sharath

Comment: http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php  This page is not  displaying anything.

Comment: how can I fix or do that ?? @Amy

Comment: remove UI operations from doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of bad http request url,As you know url will not allow any whitespace or special characters in it,So we have to encode them before making request,Please print your url and you will find solution.

Comment: I used 
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                .build().toString();
but error is occurring 
can u suggest me any code??

Comment: @Komal - do not encode your whole url..just encode thing which includes any white spaces or special characters.using `EncodeString` method.[http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-encode-java-string-send-web-server-safe-url refer this link.it may help you.\]

Comment: No..I am getting an error.I am also getting an error on a line where i have defined Log.d().